# Get column's html value closest to checkbox column, from the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table. There are columns with checkbox, when checkbox is clicked I want to get value from same row's column's named 'desc' value.

I don't know how to target that column. This is what I tried:

```
jQuery( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function() {
var value = jQuery(this).parent('TR').find('TD.desc').html();
});

jQuery( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function() {
var value = jQuery(this).closest('.desc').html();
});
```

Table looks similar to this, just with more fields:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='checkbox'>
</td>
<td class="desc">
html
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your input markup is invalid. Should be `<input type='checkbox'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parents() instead of parent(). "Parent" looks the immediate parent, while "parents" finds every superior tag.

```
$(this).parents("tr").find("td").html();
```

Do not use capital letters "TR", better user "tr". This is what you're looking for.

Comment: `parents()` gets none, one or many elements from the ancestors; `closest()` is, usually, a better choice. As for using lower or upper case, HTML (and JavaScript, typically, doesn't care). It only really matters with XHTML (which *is* lower-case).

Comment: @DooKie, Thanks Dookie, You Saved My Lot of time!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function() {
         var value = $(this).parent().parent().find('td.desc').html();
      });
});



$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function() {
         var value = $(this).parents('tr').find('td.desc').html();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on('click', function(){
        var value = $(this).parent().next().html();
    })
});
```

Example in jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/55gfdamy/.